# typeerror undefined is not a function in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a simple form which gives me below error.
TypeError: undefined is not a function on line no 20. plese help me

```
var path = require('path')
var funcs = require('./funcs')
var encodeName = funcs.encodName

var session = {
  username: process.argv[2],
  lastMessageHash: process.argv[3]
}

if (!session.username || !session.lastMessageHash) {
  console.log('Usage: node index.js <username> <hash>')
  process.exit(0)
}

// 1. load the database
var dbFile = path.join(__dirname, 'db', 'index.json')
funcs.loadDb(dbFile, function (err, db) {

  // 2. encode the name
  var encoded = encodeName(session.usrename) // error line no 20

  // 3. find the user's inbox
  var inbox = funcs.findInbox(db, encoded)

  // 4. find the next message
  var nextMessage = funcs.findNextMessage(inbox, session.lastMessageHash)

  // 5. print out the message.
  // Paste the console output into the "Solution" field and you're done!
  console.log(nextMessage)
})
```

I am working on simple page with database conncection on my node js project. i am newbe in nodejs.

Comment: How you export funcs.encodName from func file? The issue must be there. Or even show whole func.js file. Thanks.

Comment: @patel Please do not delete questions that you post. It can cause frustration to those trying to help you. If you have solved it, then put an answer for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot say for sure why it's not working since I don't know the content of `./funcs`, but there are typos in the line 3 and line 20, so it may be that because of the typo it doesn't find the proper function. You better check your code more carefully.